# Parsing to excel

Tags: java, parsing

I have a lot of lines that looks as the following :

[image]

The problem is when I parse it just has one space in between

[image]

I need to capture Description / Reference / Quantity which is

( 2.5 ML SST, BLOOD COLLECTION )
( RD25 )
( 1)

If after COLLECTION and RD25 there was 2 space i could just split text to lines and lines into values but i cannot due to the fact that there is just one space and values always different, did anyone faced similar issues, the goal is to parse lines in each page and then export to Excel. Thank you

Comment: You can still split it by a single space: the last value will be quantity and second last will be reference.

Comment: This is true i haven't thought about it, you are right i can split line to values and grab last value assuming its a quantity and second last the reference, then take whats ever left and build a single value which will be a description, thank you man @HarshalParekh

Comment: Glad to help. In future, you would want to put the input and output using the `code` formatting instead of images. It helps others to easily copy it.

Comment: @HarshalParekh agree

Comment: You also could use a regex to split  on more than one single space, or if the file is actually a fixed lenght record file, just extract substrings at approriate positions and strip them.